How to Refresh IConfiguration
I am using .Net 8 DI to load IConfiguration on startup.
It will be loading key-values from azure keyvault.
But, after few hours the key-values would change.
So how to refresh IConfiguration automatically & also manually?

For manully change the service options you could use IOptionsMonitor. Just note that you have to inject IServiceProvider to make it work.  (Direct injection of IOptionsMonitor wouldn't work.)
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

        public ValuesController(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            this._provider = provider;
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void Test()
        {

              //retrive new key from keyvalut
            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";
            var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var key = await client.GetKeyAsync("myKey");

              //get the options service you want to modify, such as AddBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options.....)
            var jwtoptionsMonitor = _provider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions>>();
            var jwtoptions = jwtoptionsMonitor.Get(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            //then you can modify jwtoptions as you like
            jwtoptions.Authority = "new value";
            jwtoptions.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey= new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));

        }
    }

You may create a background service to execute this code periodically.

Probably you want to use  Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets nuget package.
Using this package you can setup auto refresh your configuration.
More information can be found:

Documentation
SO topic

